# Convert PFX to use with Putty and Windows OpenSSH

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, puttygen

I have a Windows Server with OpenSSH. Client is connecting with user/pass using Putty for Windows. The task is to use Putty key files instead - and the keys must come from a PFX certificate.

I can setup Putty using keys where the keys are created by Putty (i.e. using Puttygen). Public key is stored on the server and everything works. But I cannot seem to convert the PFX certificate into Putty compatible keys (OpenSSH keys).

I can create PEM key files using OpenSSL but they cannot be imported by Puttygen...

Does anyone have a link or steps to get from a PFX certificate and into Putty key files?

Comment: For RSA use `openssl pkcs12 -in pfx -nocerts -nodes | openssl rsa -out trad.pem` or for any type but ed25519 use `(same) | openssl pkey -traditional -out trad.pem` (in 1.1.0 up) and puttygen should be able to read the result and convert to PPK. (putty itself requires PPK not any OpenSSH format, though puttygen can _convert_ OpenSSH formats.)

Comment: Awesome - the latter for > 1.1.0 did the trick. Thanks!